# Selenium ide: Verify "Except field X no other field exists"

Tags: selenium-ide

We have a test requirement to verify that only the expected fields appear on a page. I can verify this case as: True, the expected fields appear. But I cannot verify that "only" these fields appear. So the condition is something like:

Verify: Except field[id/name]="test" NO (input OR select) element exists.
- The above will tell me that except the field I am expecting there is no other dropdown/text/checkbox/etc on the page. This is a simple usecase; in real world ofcourse a page will have multiple fields hence I need to veirfy that except these [5] fields no other field exists.

Any idea how to do this in IDE only? Or is there any hack possible to get this verified using IDE only?

Answer (score 0):

You posted no code, so I cannot reply with any code!

The approach you could take is count the number of all fields on a page, and count number of field you are interested in. The two should match.